# Django server side application

Tags: django, server-side

I've been trying to learn Django, but I'm still pretty much a web dev newbie, so please bear with me. Maybe something is just fundamentally wrong with this question...

For example, lets say some data exists in a JSON stream that is updated constantly. I'm trying to capture bits of that data and store it in my database, and it's displayed when I visit my Django built page. I guess there's two ways to do this:

1. In my views.py, it checks the data source, updates the database, and displays the information through a html file. This just seems like it's not the right way to do it. The source would be polled every time the page is viewed.
2. I would think the correct way to do it is have an application on the server that polls the data source every 1 minute or whatever and updates the database. The views.py only displays information from the database.

Am I even thinking about this correctly? I haven't found any information/examples on how to write the application that would sit on the server and constantly update the database.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The second way is the right way to go about this, and the application that you would write to poll the json stream does not *have* to be written with django.

If you want to use the same models for the application, you can implement it as a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/), then run the command using cron at an interval. The command would poll the stream, update the database. Your view would then read the database and display the data.

If you want to do this in "realtime" (I use the word realtime here loosely), the server that is hosting the json stream should allow for "push" or a socket connection that will remain open.